# Why is there an intimate relationship between calculus and $e$?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Why did the irrational number $e$ become such a crucial part of calculus? Why didn't some other irrational number like, say, $\pi$ take the place of $e$?

Comment: I think it is not $e$ which is that crucial, but instead the expontial function $e^z$ (where $e^1 = e$). And one strong property of the exponential function is the functional equation $e^{z + w} = e^z e^w$.

Comment: Wikipedia article on $e$ covers this question pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

The roles of $e$ and $\pi$ are similar in calculus.

The number $e$ arises naturally in the solution of the simplest possible first order differential equation because $y(t)=e^t$ is the solution of $y'=y$.

In similar fashion, $\pi$ arises in the solution of the the simplest *second* order differential equation because $y(t)=\sin(t)$ and $y(t)=\cos(t)$ are the solutions of $y^{\prime\prime}=-y$.

While not immediately calculus related, it might also be mentioned that the golden ratio arises as the solution of one of the simplest *algebraic* equations, namely $x^2-x-1=0$.

Comment: You wrote that e arises naturally in the solution of the differential equation. I've only memorized this formula in school without knowing how it came to be. Can you please elaborate? I think that might answer my original question.

Answer (score 3):

$e$ is directly related to derivatives because the function $x\mapsto e^x$ *is its own derivative*. No other base has this property.

Meanwhile, $\pi$ is *also* intimately related to calculus, because any function whose *second* deriviative is the negative of the original function will be periodic with period $2\pi$.

Comment: Somewhere on this site is an answer by Qiaochu Yuan saying essentially this, but in the fancier language that $\exp$ is an eigenvector of the differentiation operator.